# Symfony : OrderBy in CollectionType

Tags: forms, symfony, orm, sql-order-by, edit

I have two tables (Player & Historique) that have a OneToMany association. In my PlayerType form, I have a CollectionType with an entry_type to my HistoriqueType. My question is about the order in which the data from HistoriqueType arrives. For the moment, it appears in `ASC` order of the `id`. But I would like it to appear in `ASC` order of the years (season).

Here are my two entities :

```
<?php

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=PlayerRepository::class)
 */
class Player
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Historique::class, mappedBy="player", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval = true)
     */
    public $playerHistoriques;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->playerHistoriques = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

And my Historique Class :

```
<?php

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=HistoriqueRepository::class)
 */
class Historique
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Club::class, inversedBy="historiques")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $club;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Season::class, inversedBy="historiques")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"season" = "ASC"})
 */
private $season;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Player::class, inversedBy="playerHistoriques")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $player;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Position::class, inversedBy="historiques")
 */
private $position;
```

My PlayerType :

```
<?php

class PlayerType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('playerHistoriques', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => HistoriqueType::class,
            'entry_options' => [
                'label' => false
            ],
            'by_reference' => false,
            'allow_add' => true
        ])
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Player::class,
    ]);
}
}
```

And My HistoriqueType:

```
<?php

class HistoriqueType extends AbstractType
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder
        ->add('club', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Club::class,
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'label' => false,
            'required' => false,
            'placeholder' => '-',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                    ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');
            }
        ])
        ->add('season', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Season::class,
            'choice_label' => 'year',
            'label' => false,
            'placeholder' => '-',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                    ->orderBy('s.year', 'ASC');
            }
        ])
        ->add('position', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Position::class,
            'choice_label' => 'position',
            'label' => false,
            'placeholder' => '-',
            'required' => false
        ])
    ;
    
}


public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Historique::class,
        'method' => 'get',
        'csrf_protection' => false
    ]);
}

public function getBlockPrefix() {
    return '';
}
}
```

In my edit form, I would like to order my collectionType by 'season' => 'ASC', in order to have the years in chronological order even in my edit form.

I have tried a query_builder like so in my PlayerType :

```
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('h')
                          ->orderBy('h.season', 'ASC');
            }
```

But it generated an error since collectionTypes cannot have queries in them.

I have tried to order it automatically in my PlayerEntity `@ORM\OrderBy({"season" = "ASC"})`  but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

OrderBy must be in Palyer entity in OneToMany relation not in Historique

```
/**
 *@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Historique::class, mappedBy="player", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval = true)
 *@ORM\OrderBy({"season" = "ASC"})
*/
public $playerHistoriques;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Yes it works. I was putting the Order By in the wrong places. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your Historique Entity change the order by to **year** instead of ***season*** (I believe in your other form you are sorting by the year so hopefully this is the property you are looking to sort by).

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Season::class, inversedBy="historiques")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"year" = "ASC"})
 */
private $season;
```

You should be able to remove the query builder now, unless you need to narrow the selection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately it did not work... In my edit form, my collectionType is still not being rendered in ASC order of the years, but rather in ASC order of id.